# Primary key auto generated by Oracle, which is @Id in my Entity

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity whose value for an @Id column is generated from a sequence from the DB side for every insert i.e. I do not have to populate this value from my service while performing insert.

If I don't populate a value, JPA/Hibernate is complaining my @Id cannot be null. If I use a Oracle Sequence Generator and populate a value for my @Id while insert, my DB complains saying "cannot insert into a generated always identity column"

I am using an Oracle10g Dialect.

I tried all strategies for GenerationType - AUTO, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE, TABLE, without mentioning any sequence.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "INTERACTION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public BigDecimal getINTERACTION_ID() {
    return INTERACTION_ID;
}
```

Unfortunately my DB team doesn't agree to change the restrictions on this column.
I am looking for an option where I can insert the data through my persistent object without having to populate value for @Id column and have the DB auto insert for me.

Here is the part of my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
(
INTERACTION_ID NUMBER(28, 0) DEFAULT "MY_SCHEMA"."ISEQ$$_85362".nextval NOT 
NULL,
...,
...)
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: where's the rest of your sequence definition in JPA annotations? A simple inspection of ANY JPA documentation would tell you how to do that. Post the DDL of the column

Comment: what error do you get with IDENTITY generator ?

Comment: @Sikorski - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support identity key generation

Comment: then you should change your table DDL, make an explicit sequence and don't use the default clause for it. In your Java code use SequenceGenerator with strategy SEQUENCE, give the sequence name there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set insertable and updatable to false to avoid that Hibernate is trying to set the id.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "INTERACTION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public BigDecimal getINTERACTION_ID() {
    return INTERACTION_ID;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It says "org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()"

Comment: Nope. It says "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support identity key generation". I have tried SEQUUENCE, TABLE and AUTO as well.

Comment: In that case I don't think that this is possible.

Comment: At least the `insertable=false` approach saved the day for me when oracle denied inserting upon error message "... `GENERATED ALWAY` ..."